# c# two nested if statements, one else

Tags: c#, if-statement

Please excuse the question that seems simple, but for some reason I cannot think of an elegant solution at the moment.

I have the following situation:

```
    if (Request.QueryString["name"] != null)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["name"].ToString() != "")
        {
            nameSpan.InnerHtml = Request.QueryString["name"].ToString();
        }

    }
```

The problem is, if I want to hide the `nameSpan` if querystring["name"] is either null or emtpy.  The ugly solution would be:

```
if (Request.QueryString["name"] != null)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["name"].ToString() != "")
    {
        nameSpan.InnerHtml = Request.QueryString["name"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        nameSpan.Visible = false;
    }
}
else
{
    nameSpan.Visible = false;
}
```

I would like to have a situation where both the `nameSpan.Visible = false;` sections could be merged into **one** area so I only have to write it **once**.

As far as I am aware, it is not possible to do the following:

```
if (Request.QueryString["name"] != null && Request.QueryString["name"].ToString() != "")
{
    nameSpan.InnerHtml = Request.QueryString["name"].ToString();
}
else
{
    nameSpan.Visible = false;
}
```

But please tell me if I am wrong!  If you have a different solution which changes the logic then I am more than happy to have different views! Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can use `&&` like that.

Comment: @p.s.w.g will it not give an exception if the value is null?

Comment: No, `&&` uses short-circuiting, so if the first condition is false, it won't evaluate the second condition. See [&& Operator (C# reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx)

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thank you for the link. I actually just re-tested and you're right that it short-circuits.  Maybe I accidently put the .ToString() as the first case before because we had a problem where it gave an exception doing it, hence why I was using nested ifs to avoid any problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `&&` solution should be fine. If left side of `&&` is false, right side it not evaluated so there will be no exception.

If you want, you could use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` static method:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["name"]))
{
    nameSpan.InnerHtml = Request.QueryString["name"].ToString();
}
else
{
    nameSpan.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this method, thank you for helping me learn something new! I will mark the answer as correct when it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

if you are after compact code, I'd use next (NameValueCollection returns null if key does not exist, and indexer returns string):

```
nameSpan.InnerHtml = Request.QueryString["name"];
nameSpan.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameSpan.InnerHtml);
```